# ListView lagging only when widgets in the list are Video_Player widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to achieve a scrollable List with videos. I'm using the video_player widget and wrapping the player in a Card with a simple button.
Now i noticed that whenever I use ListView.builder with videos in the list, it is extremely lagging, especially when scrolling back up. i'm posting a GiF bellow if you would like to see the behaviour.
I have this problem ONLY when I have Videos in the list.
If I replace the videos with a simple Image widget, the scrolling is smooth and runs as intended. (Also provided a GiF below)

When I scroll through the list I get this message in my Console:

```
flutter: Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

And I think (but not sure) that this is the cause of the problem, maybe the way I implemented the video_player plugin (?)

```
class VideoPlayPause extends StatefulWidget {
  VideoPlayPause(this.controller);

  final VideoPlayerController controller;

  @override
  _VideoPlayPauseState createState() => _VideoPlayPauseState();
}

class _VideoPlayPauseState extends State<VideoPlayPause> {

//This Part here 
_VideoPlayPauseState() {
    listener = () {
      setState(() {});
    };
  }
```

Maybe its setting state every time I scroll ?

I tried flutter run --release but saw no difference at all.
I'm running the app on a physical Iphone X.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MVP_Test1'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: videoUrl.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return Card(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.live_tv),
                      title: Text("Nature"),
                    ),
                    Stack(
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight +
                            const FractionalOffset(-0.1, -0.1),
                        children: <Widget>[
// If I replace this with Image.asset("..."), the scrolling is very smooth.
                          AssetPlayerLifeCycle(
                              videoUrl[i],
                              (BuildContext context,
                                      VideoPlayerController controller) =>
                                  AspectRatioVideo(controller)),
                        ]),
                  ],
                ),
                ButtonTheme.bar(
                  child: ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('ADD VIDEO'),
                        onPressed: () {
/* ... */
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Result when I run Flutter Analyze

```
flutter analyze
Analyzing mvp_1...                                                      
No issues found! (ran in 1.9s)
```

You can see how when scrolling back up it looks like the app is skipping frames or something. Here's a video:
https://giphy.com/gifs/u48BNQ13r15Zay5SnN

Here's a video with photos instead of videos: 
https://giphy.com/gifs/236RKyA8y1pfecmR1d

Comment: Did you make any progress on this @tester_s25?